# Code check: Force simplified inequalities to be of form `expr > 0`

Tags: function-construction, code-review

`Simplify` is a nice fast function that cleans up simple inequalities.  For example:

```
Simplify[c (a - b) > 0, Assumptions -> c > 0]
```

> a > b

But I need the output inequality of the form `expr > 0`, and ultimately I want to extract `expr`.  So I wrote a tiny function that gets it:

```
getGtrZero[expr_, assump_] := Part[#, 1] - Part[#, 2] &@Simplify[expr > 0, assump]
```

Test:

```
getGtrZero[c (a - b), c > 0]
```

> a - b

This seems to be working ok, but this crucially requires that the output uses the function `Greater`.  Is this a robust way to get the simplified `expr` that is going to be greater than zero?

**Assumptions about input inequality:**  The input inequality will always have head `Greater` and will be a comparison of two simple polynomials of various symbols (involving only plus, minus and times).

Comment: `Simplify[c (a - b) < 0,  Assumptions -> c > 0] /. {x__ > y__ -> x - y > 0,  x__ < y__ -> y - x > 0}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force `Simplify` to return inequalities with head Greater and  right hand side 0 by adapting the `ComplexityFunction` and adding a transformation function that will convert a `Less` expression to a `Greater` expression:

```
Simplify[a<0, 
ComplexityFunction->(If[#[[2]]===0 && Head[#]===Greater,1,1000] LeafCount[#1]&),
TransformationFunctions->{If[Head[#]===Less, Greater[-#[[1]],-#[[2]]], #]& , Automatic}
]

(* -a > 0 *)

Simplify[c (a - b) > 0,
Assumptions -> c > 0, 
ComplexityFunction -> (If[#[[2]] === 0, 1, 1000] LeafCount[#1] &),
TransformationFunctions -> {If[Head[#] === Less, Greater[-#[[1]], -#[[2]]], #] & , Automatic}
]

(* a - b > 0 *)
```